# Connection timed out fatal: Could not read from remote repository. GitLab

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, gitlab

I am new to aws. I have two instances running up. On one ubuntu instance gitlab is installed and can be accessed by its public key. On second ubuntu instance source code is available. I have a private git repo in gitlab. Whenever i am trying to clone my private repo on my second ubuntu server i get an error:

```
$ git clone git@ec2-13-xx-xx-xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:andalibshadani/mysimpleproject.git

ssh: connect to host ec2-13-235-xx-xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I have already added my public ssh key `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to gitlab server. But i am still facing the same issue.

I can't able to push/pull/clone to my gitlab instance.

If anyone know please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Maybe your ssh-key has been removed from your ssh agent. Try setting `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` before you clone the repository.

Comment: I have done it. But still having same problem.

Comment: Check that (1) the host name resolves to the correct IP address; (2) you don't have a firewall blocking access to port 22 (ssh) *on* that IP address. This appears to be a network configuration issue and has nothing to do with Git or GitLab.